# Rails - How to group_by with many models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this chain of models:

[image]

And I have a list of `suboptions`. I would like to `group_by` the suboptions by each of the above fathers.

So, it would be divided into Categories, which would be divided into activities, which would be divided into options. Do you see?

How can I do this??

```
Suboptions.all.group_by(???)
# or
Suboptions.all.order_by(????)
# or ????
```

Example:

**Suboptions**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | option_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         2 |
|  3 |         2 |
|  4 |         4 |
|  5 |         3 |
+----+-----------+
```

**Options**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | activity_id |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |
|  2 |           2 |
|  3 |           1 |
|  4 |           3 |
+----+-------------+
```

**Activities**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | category_id |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |
|  2 |           2 |
|  3 |           1 |
+----+-------------+
```

**Categories**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | cat1 |
|  2 | cat2 |
+----+------+
```

then the search should return the suboptions with ids in the following order: **[1,5,4,2,3]**
*( try to visualize it from the category to the suboption )*

Comment: `GROUP BY` in sql is meant to group selected records by a given criteria and then return the first of each group. Is this what you want? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_group_by.htm

Comment: Could you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: @nicooga I just realized what i actually need is an `order_by`..

Comment: So you want to order the suboptions by its category's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the size of the data set, sounds like you want to do a join, followed by an order

```
Suboption.joins(option: {activity: :category}).order('categories.name')
```

Will that work for you?

Comment: Almost it! I joined all the tables and then ordered them all by their ids (category_id, activity_id, option_id and suboption_id)